# Why these links are different and works same?

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, hyperlink

```
https://www.google.com/

https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F
```

What is the different between above two links. And how can i convert Ist link to 2nd link using javascript or regex. Please help and give a expert advice.

Comment: You are searching for [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Hi @User863 I am not sure. First of all i just want to know what is the difference between these 2 urls. Then i will think to convert it.

Comment: All else being equal, they will not work the same: https://jsbin.com/widejixisa/1/edit?html,output

Comment: @Quentin Then why some websites convert urls like in 2nd format. Is there any benefit?

Comment: guys this is looking interesting may be get something good related to it.

Comment: @Rambler — I've never seen a website do that. Perhaps there is some specific context lacking from your question.

Comment: @Quentin this thing i found in the tracking links. Like in the google ads.

Comment: @Rambler — Maybe `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F` isn't the **whole** URL? And you've just shown us a piece of one?

Comment: @Quentin Let me found some more info about and i will update here also.

Comment: I just added a example here. As i didn't know that what is these type of url's called. May be there must be some specific name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
decodeURIComponent('https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F')
```

URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted over the Internet.

URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.

Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.

URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

Answer (score 0):

I can help with the first question:  There's no difference between the two links.  One is encoded using [UTF-8 codes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) instead of the symbols. You can verify this by converting the URL in a [URL Encoder/Decoder](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).
Somebody else will have to help with the conversion using JS or regex.

Comment: nice. this is good.Also i just want to know why we need it?